# Excel Lookup for multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

I have two sheets in Excel. First one is city/branch name and the second is the branch's sales.

sheet 1:

```
City    Branch         

NY      GoldenStar
NY      Aquta
NY      Orgi
Oregon  Orgi
L.A     Orgi
Oregon  GoldenStar
....
```

Sheet 2 is detailed sales for each city

```
                   Branch
City       GeldenStar  Aquta  Orgi

NY             45       456     90
L.A            155      345     34
Oregon          9        23     17
```

How can I use lookup function to assign each branch sale to sheet 1 ( I want to have a result like this :)

sheet 1:

```
City    Branch        Sale 

NY      GoldenStar     45
NY      Aquta          456 
NY      Orgi           90
Oregon  Orgi           17
L.A     Orgi           34
Oregon  GoldenStar      9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH` for this task. Consider this example:

[image]

Use the `VLOOKUP` to look into the data range (without headers) with the City name as the key. You get the column number from using `MATCH` with the Branch name into the header range.